# Show the number of messages within a group in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

In outlook 2010 I am unable to show the number of messages within a particular group. For example, I categorise my messages and then when I sort by category, there is no way to show the number of messages within that(those) category(ies).

Previous versions of outlook would do this by default, but I am not finding the setting to do this in Outlook 2010. If it isn't possible, is there anything method to count those messages within a group/category easily?

Answer (score 1):

I accomplished this with a Custom Search folder and then adding it to my "Favorites" view for convenience.

I right-clicked on Search Folders and did "New Search Folder..."
Take the bottom option in the list to create a Custom Search Folder.
Click Choose and give it a name.
For criteria go to "More Choices" tab and check "unread" and save that.
Finally, select the folders that you want to be counted/included and you're done.

If you want it up in the Favorites list just right click on your new custom search folder and "Add to favorites."

Hope that helps.

Comment: This doesn't work for me for showing the number of emails from each sender.  I get the number of unread, but not the total number.

Answer (score -1):

For Outlook 2010, highlight subfolder in your Inbox, or highlight Inbox itself, right click and in drop-down menu choose Properties.  On the General tab in Properties box, you'll see the Default option is "Show number of unread items".  To change this option so that you can see the total no. of messages in the folder, simply click the radio button that says "Show total number of items".  Works like a charm!